# How to get a list of all users registered before a given date?

Tags: php, wp-user-query

I was expecting to be able to do something like the following which I thought would return all users that have registered before a given date:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'before' => current_time( 'mysql' )
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

However, unlike `WP_Query`, `WP_User_Query` doesn't support the `date_query` parameter so the above code doesn't work.

How can I get a list of all users registered before a given date?

Comment: This is now supported since 4.1. I updated the Codex when I was working on [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/196774/26350).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Method #1: The `pre_user_query` hook:

There are not many filters available, but you can try the [`pre_user_query`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/user.php#L706) hook:

```
// Add filter:
add_action(    'pre_user_query', 'wpse_filter_by_reg_date' );

// Query:
$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// Remove filter:
remove_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse_filter_by_reg_date' );
```

where the filter callback is:

```
/**
 * Filter WP_User_Query by user_registered date
 *
 * @see   http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160826/26350
 * @param WP_User_Query The current WP_User_Query instance
 */

function wpse_filter_by_reg_date( $q )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $q->query_where .=  $wpdb->prepare(
        " AND {$wpdb->users}.user_registered >= '%s' ",
        date( "Y-m-d" )
    );
}
```

You can then modify the filter callback to your needs.

### Method #2: `WP_User_Query` with custom query variables:

You can also make this more dynamic, by using the custom string parameters `_registered` and  `_registered_compare`. Then your query could be:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'             => 'login',
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    '_registered'         => date( 'Y-m-d' ),
    '_registered_compare' => '>=',
);
$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

where:

```
/**
 * Add support for the custom '_registered' and '_registered_compare'
 * string input parameters in WP_User_Query().
 *
 * @see   http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160826/26350
 * @param WP_User_Query The current WP_User_Query instance
 */

function wpse_registered_filter( $q )
{
    if( isset( $q->query_vars['_registered'] )
        && isset( $q->query_vars['_registered_compare'] )
        && is_string( $q->query_vars['_registered_compare'] )
    )
    {   
        // Input:
        $registered = $q->query_vars['_registered'];
        $compare    = $q->query_vars['_registered_compare'];

        // Init:     
        $available_compares = array( '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '!=' );

        // Default compare:
        if( ! in_array( $compare, $available_compares, TRUE ) )
            $compare = '=';

        // Modify query:
        global $wpdb;                                               
        $q->query_where .=  $wpdb->prepare(
            " AND {$wpdb->users}.user_registered {$compare} '%s' ",
            $registered
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse_registered_filter' );
```

### Method #3: Manual SQL:

Responding to the comment below, this is an example how you can write the SQL manually:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->users} WHERE {$wpdb->users}.user_registered >= '%s' ",
        current_time( 'mysql' )
    );
    $uids = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
```

Comment: Think your approach might be faster than mine :-)

Comment: Maybe, but some prefer to work in PHP instead of SQL, hence your solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks @birgire. Is there any advantage of the `WP_User_Query... pre_user_query` approach over a simple custom select query?

Comment: I think you could ask the same about `WP_Query` + hooks versus a custom SQL query ;-) I usually prefer the "flexibility" of `WP_Query` or `WP_User_Query` in this case. Additionally the output of `WP_User_Query` is an array of `WP_User` objects.

Comment: Good point about the output being an array of WP_User objects. That is quite helpful. In my particular case, I just need an array of user IDs. My knowledge of custom SQL queries could be better. Would this be the right way to do it?

`$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_registered <= current_time( 'mysql' )";
 
$user_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $query, 0 );`

Comment: I updated the answer with a manual SQL query. ps: the default offset is `0` for `get_col()`.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, much appreciate your help! Time for me to learn all this :)

Comment: you're welcome, great if you can use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) to retrieve a list of all user's ID's and then pass that to [`get_userdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) to retrieve a user's registration date.

You can then sort and exclude users from that according to a specific date and time.

Here is my idea

```
<?php
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
        'fields'    => 'ID',
    ) );
    $users = $user_query->get_results();

    foreach( $users as $user ) {
        $user_object = get_userdata( $user );
        $cutoffdate = '2013-07-01 00:00:01';

        if( $user_object->user_registered < $cutoffdate ) {
            echo '<p>' . $user_object->display_name; 
            echo '</br>';
            echo $user_object->user_registered . '</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Pieter, a nice approach. As you point out in the comments on @birgire's answer, it may be a slightly slower way of doing it, especially if there are many users

Comment: I totally agree. I just tried to show how it is done without custom sql, but to be honest, I like @birgire solution more and would also choose his above mine :-) Just glad his solution panned out for you. Enjoy