# Getting users who registered 360 days from current date

Tags: users, wpdb, sql

As per the title, what I want to do is run a custom query that (using WP-Cron) will run once a day to check for users who registered exactly 360 days before the current date (don't need time, just date) and gather their `ID`. I have this:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->users} 
     WHERE {$wpdb->users}.user_registered = CURRENT-DATE-MINUS-360-DAYS";
);
$userdata = HOW-DO-I-GET-THE-RESULTS-IN-AN-ARRAY
```

Where the bit in caps represents the bit I have no idea what to do :) Any help much appreciated.

Comment: [`$wpdb->get_results()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results)? And also [look at this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results).

Comment: Hi Sisir, thanks for the reply - I think you've linked to the same page twice though..?

Comment: Sorry long day! Here is the second link http://stackoverflow.com/a/2041619/550907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [peeked](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/user.php#L794) into the `WP_User_Query` class and it supports a `WP_Date_Query` query on the user registration date.

So we could use:

```
$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

or simply:

```
$users = get_users( $args );
```

where:

```
$args = [
    'fields'     => 'ID',
    'number'     => 8,
    'date_query' => [
        [ 'before' => '359 days ago midnight' ],
        [ 'after'  => '360 days ago midnight', 'inclusive' => true ],
   ] 
];
```

This generates the following SQL query (*expanded view*):

```
SELECT wp_users.ID 
    FROM wp_users 
    WHERE 1=1 
        AND ( 
                wp_users.user_registered >= '2014-08-10 00:00:00' 
            AND       
                wp_users.user_registered < '2014-08-11 00:00:00' 
        ) 
    ORDER BY user_login ASC 
    LIMIT 10;
```

where today is `2015-08-05`.

It looks like we should update the Codex on [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function, regarding the `date_query` argument.

Comment: *It looks like we should update the Codex* Looks like a job specially for you :-)

Comment: it looks like I've been hired for that job ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: I've updated the *date_query* info on the [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) page in the Codex. This was also missing on the [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) page, so I added a [new section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Date_Parameters) there with an example. @PieterGoosen

Comment: Great, that should help many others out there. Can't upvote you again for that though, hahaha, but great work. ;-)

Comment: Hopefully it will help someone out there - they could even enhance it or correct it ;-)

Comment: Great, you're welcome. The `date_query` is rather flexible and can be very helpful. @kev

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT *, (DATEDIFF(NOW(),user_registered)) AS daydiff FROM {$wpdb->users} WHERE 'daydiff' = 360");
```

Comment: Hi TrangDinhVan, thanks for your reply - I'll have a go with that and let you know how it goes :)